# Connect 400 W LED light to a small relay module

Tags: voltage, power, current, relay

I want to make an automatic relay switch for my LED light for growing a vegetable.
The LED says it will use 400 W.

I have a small *relay module* which says 10 A, 250 V, so I think it could handle to around 2300 W without problem, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Am I right?

[image]

This is the LED light adapter:

[image]

Comment: What is the voltage that you want to switch?

Comment: I edited the question and added a screenshot of an adapter for the led light.

Comment: Im not sure, but I think it says 36-95 volts

Comment: Yes, but it's 36-95V *DC*, for which there are no specifications on the relay. You'll have to look up in the relay's data sheet what its maximum DC voltages are.

Comment: You would want to switch the mains input of that LED driver, not the output. It is rated at 240 V, so if it outputs 400 W with an efficiency of, say, 80% (it will be better than that), then the current on the mains side will be about 2 A, which is within the rating printed on the relay.

Comment: thanks for the answers! Why is better to switch the input rather than ouput of the driver?

Comment: @MarcelKopera I wrote that only as a comment, not an answer, because I am not a qualified electrician. It's better to switch the mains because then more of the wiring is disconnected, so there is less hazard, and anyway you would have to get a different relay to switch several amps DC.

Comment: Also note that DC is more difficult to "switch" than AC, because it does not "cross zero". In other words, if an arc develops when disconnecting AC, it will extinguish itself when the voltage crosses zero volts, whereas DC never does that, so it requires better switching.

Comment: I took a look to datasheet, it says: max voltage 277VAC/30VDC, max 15A / 10A, max switching power: 2770VA 210W. Electric outlet in my country is 100AC, which is in range(95-240) from led driver, so should it works?

Comment: So you havent actually tried if the LED works with that LED driver ? I thought you only had a question on how to switch it on/off. The 210W max switching power is the concerning part there. Are you sure you're not missing a zero ?

Comment: Im quite sure    https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.generationrobots.com/media/JQC-3FF-v1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwis34uGku7zAhU1NKYKHbsIDqgQFnoECDkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2gzjXQUbRw3BhzhtmvPKRX

Comment: Its is a LED driver + leds selling as an one product, so I think it will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is presumed that the LED light has a matching adaptor that works.

It would be advisable to switch the adaptor on the AC side as the relay contact rating is more than adequate for that purpose.

Comment: Simple but proper answer for the question! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Marcel!